# Java JSP Check if Parameter = 0 and copy it to variable

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have to write a small message board as a homework and struggle with a, as I believe, really easy task:

The user is clicking on "Answer" below an article, which is bringing him to the answer.jsp?id=123. There is an input form for his text which submits his entry to a saveanswer.jsp.
The answer.jsp does a mySQL query do retrieve some data, and here do I need to make a "if-then-else" and (I believe) store the result in a variable to use it for the submit-form.

answer.jsp?id=123

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from forum where id=<%= request.getParameter("id") %>;
</sql:query>


<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="RE: <c:out value="${row.title}"/>"/> <br/>
<textarea name="answertext" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea> <br/>

<input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="<%= request.getParameter("Id")%>">
```

There is a field answer_id in the database, and I need to check:

```
    if answer_id == 0; 
then 
    answer_id=id; 
else 
    answer_id_answer_id //do nothing
```

The result should then be the value of the hidden "answer_id" field.

Unfortunatly, I was not able to get an if-else with the db data or a variable declaration working :/
I tried for 2 days now, you're my last hope.

Thanks for reading, I really would appreciate your help!

Best regards,
DataSlayer

Comment: "?id='12';SELECT youHaveBeenHacked FROM DUAL"

Comment: IMHO, you should move the sql query thing and your if into the code handling the "saveanswer" (do some reading about "servlet" maybe)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are looking to set the value of the hidden input depending on some values, not sure where answer_id is coming from but you want to use a simple condition, even better a ternary condition

```
${empty value? other:value}
```

In this simple line, value and other are both variable, if value is empty, this insert other. Update this to your case, since I don't really know where answer_id come from (the DB but from which table)

**SQL INJECTION**

As RC point it out, you are open to SQL injection with your query since you add directly the parameter into a query.

Someone could set the parameter as

```
0; drop table forum
```

This will result in a query like :

```
SELECT * from forum where id=0; drop table forum;
```

Dropping your table. 
Never concat parameter receive from the client to you query, you never know what it can be. If this is from you, you should be able to trust yourself but the client, NEVER!

To prevent it, use the parameters system provided (never used it but should work)

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="count">
  SELECT * from forum where id=?
  <sql:param value="${ request.getParameter("id") }" />
</sql:update>
```

This will prevent the injection to happened.